# Add column but duplicate all other row values in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to expand my dataframe by repeating a row 24 times while adding an additional column for "hour". Here is an example of my data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(Tmin = sample(0:3), Tmax = sample(4:7), Day = rep(1:4))
```

I want to expand this table such that each row is repeated with the same Tmin, Tmax, and Day 24 times, with an additional column `mydata$hour` where the numbers 1:24 are repeated for each day. All other values (Tmin, Tmax, Day) stay the same for each row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repeat each row index 24 times and then assign new `hour` column from 1 to 24 using recycling techinique.

```
newdata <- mydata[rep(seq_len(nrow(mydata)), each = 24),]
newdata$hour <- 1:24
```

---

Couple of `tidyverse` options :

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% tidyr::uncount(24) %>% group_by(Day) %>% mutate(hour = 1:24)
```

and

```
mydata %>% group_by(Day) %>% slice(rep(row_number(), 24)) %>% mutate(hour = 1:24)
```

Comment: Thank you - I tried your first option but received this error: ```Error: Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data. x Existing data has 6912 rows. x Assigned data has 24 rows. i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.```

Comment: Your second option works - Thanks!!

Comment: @NorthLattitude It looks like your actual data is a tibble and not a dataframe. if you do `newdata <- data.frame(newdata)` and try it again it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `lapply` and `dplyr::mutate` .

```
library(dplyr)
    set.seed(1)
    mydata <- data.frame(Tmin = sample(0:3), Tmax = sample(4:7), Day = rep(1:4))
    newdata <- as.data.frame(lapply(mydata, rep, 24))
    newdata %>% 
        mutate(hour = rep(c(1:24), times = 4))
```